# Time the connect syscall

Tags: linux, sockets, system-calls

I would like to see how much time it takes for connect syscall. I get the code for a simple TCP client. However, the program will wait for the server to respond after connect. How can I make it return right after syscall or using some other ways to time the syscall time?

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h> 

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int sockfd = 0, n = 0;
    char recvBuff[1024];
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr; 

    if(argc != 2) {
        printf("\n Usage: %s <ip of server> \n",argv[0]);
        return 1;
    } 

    memset(recvBuff, '0',sizeof(recvBuff));
    if((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
        printf("\n Error : Could not create socket \n");
        return 1;
    } 

    memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr)); 

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(5000); 

    if(inet_pton(AF_INET, argv[1], &serv_addr.sin_addr)<=0) {
        printf("\n inet_pton error occured\n");
        return 1;
    } 

    if( connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) {
       printf("\n Error : Connect Failed \n");
       return 1;
    }
      printf("\nhello\n");  

    while ( (n = read(sockfd, recvBuff, sizeof(recvBuff)-1)) > 0) {
        recvBuff[n] = 0;
        if(fputs(recvBuff, stdout) == EOF) {
            printf("\n Error : Fputs error\n");
        }
    } 

    if(n < 0)
    {
        printf("\n Read error \n");
    } 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `strace -T` to profile your program? Or some other profiler like [systemtap](https://sourceware.org/systemtap/)

Comment: good suggestion, but that does not help because strace also follows the execution. So it also stucks at the connect call.

Comment: What do you mean "stuck"? The connect call is not complete until the tcp handshake is complete. So it's not stuck. It's doing its job. Your question isn't clear because you imply you want to somehow time `connect` before it completes. So at what point is that exactly that you want to time?

Comment: I want to know the system call time for connect (from userland call to kernel respond). Once the kernel handles the connect syscall. Then control transfer back to user land right? I am not interested in how connect handles incoming data.

Comment: Yes. But that's the point. The `connect` does not transfer back to the user until the tcp connection is really established. It's nothing to do with user data. So the time you get from strace is indeed the real `connect` syscall time.

Comment: Oh come on. Get rid of the `read()` loop, of course. @kaylum Read the code.

Comment: @EJP Oh. Perhaps I have totally misunderstood the question and overlooked the obvious.

Comment: I suppose you could set the socket to non-blocking and then see how long it takes connect() to return -1/EINPROGRESS, but I'm unclear on why that information would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

> However, the program will wait for the server to respond after connect.

Yes, and it does so here:

```
while ( (n = read(sockfd, recvBuff, sizeof(recvBuff)-1)) > 0) {
    recvBuff[n] = 0;
    if(fputs(recvBuff, stdout) == EOF) {
        printf("\n Error : Fputs error\n");
    }
}
```

> How can I make it return right after syscall

Err, remove the receive loop above?

Comment: after removing, it stucks at connect. How do I set it to nonblocking?

Comment: It is *supposed* to be 'stuck at `connect()`'. ***That's what you are measuring.***

Comment: I do not want it to stuck at connect. Can I get a connect syscall and immediate return or use some sort of non blocking mechansim after I make the connect call?